Is interest expense on money borrowed from an S corporation to purchase an interest in that corporation deductible?
Consider the following scenario:

I purchase an interest in an S corporation.
To fund that purchase, I simultaneously enter into a loan agreement to borrow the money and pay it back over a number of years.
The loan charges an interest rate at approximately the Applicable Federal Rate (AFR) to avoid any imputed income from a below market loan.

IRS Publication 550 implies to me that the interest on such a loan might be deductible:

Pass-through entities. If you use borrowed funds to buy an interest in a partnership or S corporation, then the interest on those funds must be allocated based on the assets of the entity. If you contribute to the capital of the entity, you can make the allocation using any reasonable method.

Am I right in interpreting this as “the interest paid is deductible as an investment expense against any net investment income I have?”
If so, can someone explain the bit about how the interest expense must be allocated according to the entity’s assets?

If you borrowed from the S-Corp to purchase a stake in it, then the interest is income to the corporation and an investment expense to you.
If you are a 100% owner then you need to recognize the interest income. If the interest is deductible for you, then this is a complete wash (given that S-Corp is a pass-through entity) and as such will not affect your taxes in any way. If you're not a 100% owner then the other owners will recognize their portion of the income and you may be able to deduct your interest as an investment expense (offsetting your portion of the interest income from the S-Corp).
See the IRS Form 4952 and instructions.
The allocation mentioned in Pub. 550 refers to the use of funds. Only investment interest is deductible, so if you acquire an S-Corp you need to allocate the funds based on the assets of the corp. Since you're borrowing from the corp - you're not adding to the capital, so you do need to allocate appropriately. Pub 550 sends you to Pub. 334 for the discussion of deductible interest expense.

Thanks for the answer. A follow up: allocating the expense needs to be done based on the use of the funds. Pub 334 seems to speak on the distinction between personal and business use. If I am purchasing a minority stake, and am not using any of the business’ assets for personal use, is that the type of allocation you’re referring to? Or, if the funds that I’m putting in are being distributed to existing shareholders that are selling me their shares, is that treated differently?

@user3639172738 I suggest hiring a CPA. The devil is in the details.
